# Can you listen to key events inside a frame if the origin is different?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, addeventlistener, same-origin-policy

I am trying to put a keydown listener on my page.  However, my page contains an iFrame, and the handler does not fire if I click inside the iFrame and push my key.  I've tried various formulas from around the web to access the document inside the iFrame and put a listener on it, but it doesn't seem to work.

The content in the document is not from the same origin.  It comes from a different domain from my website.

Can I listen for the keydown event?  Or is that not possible?

Comment: Could you inject some JS code (similar to how a [bookmarklet works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)) to capture your desired keystrokes?

Comment: I thought I could construct an example that works, but iframes are weird, cross origin iframes moreso.  I got some examples working with same origin webpages, but not from different domains.  In fact my same origin webpages worked by setting the event on the iframe.contentWindow, which seems to be blocked when cross origin.

Comment: I konw Its old question, but because Im bored I will answer it anyway :) You can use element.focus() on your top element. So let say you will add click listener on your iframe. each time when is clicked call focus. Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer (from my understanding): you can't listen to events such as key presses and so on because it would involve binding listeners to elements within the document, and if you had access to such elements then you could theoretically modify the contents of said document, which is undesirable if someone that does not own the content is embedding it on their page. That said, you can fire an `onload` event for the iframe or overlay a `div` using some CSS positioning that will have key listeners on them.